# Sending form to a seperate page

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to take a form for inputting you email and send it as text to display on a separate page. I have added the only code I think you would need from the two pages, if you need more let me know! Any help at all is appreciated more than you know!

SignUpEmail.js

```
xport default class SignUpEmailPage extends Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#A2A2A2',
      inputValue: '', //add state here
    };
  }

  updateInputValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        inputValue: event.target.value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        
        {/* Email Input */}
      <Container style = {styles.emailInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel >
            <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Email Address</Label>
                <Input
                value = {this.state.inputValue}
                onChange={this.updateInputValue}                
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}               
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
                />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Container>
```

**EDIT - I have added my styles in case there is an issue there**

After adding the updates below I still have nothing, I didnt bother putting them here but everything else is exactly how its copied here!

CreatePassword.js

```
export default class CreatePasswordPage extends Component {

  /* Colors Input label*/
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#A2A2A2'};}
  
  render() {

    const {inputValue} = this.props.route.params;

    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
       
         {/* Password Input */}
      <Container style = {styles.passwordInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel>
           <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>Password</Label>
              <Input
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#F7018D'})}
                
                onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
         
              />
         </Item>
       </Form>
      </Container>

        <View style={styles.containerHeader}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Create a Password</Text>
        </View>
        
      <View style={styles.containerCaption}>   
        <Text style={styles.caption}> Lets create your Password for 
 
        </Text> 
      </View>
      <View>   
    <Text style={styles.caption}>{inputValue}</Text> 
      </View>

      <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <ContinueButton
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PhoneVerification')} 
      /> 
      </View>
    </View>
    );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerMain: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#1E2028',
    },
    containerHeader: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 310,
        left: 325
  },
  containerCaption: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 140,
    bottom: 490,
  },
  containerCaption2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 196,
    bottom: 470,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  containerBottom: {
    
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 270
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 5,
    bottom: 233
  }, 
  caption:
  {
   color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'left',  
  },
  passwordInput: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#1E2028',
    width: 350,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 225,
    left: 3
  },
  textInput: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',   
  },
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
// SignUpEmail.js

navigateToCreatePasswordScreen = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("CreatePassword", {
    inputValue: this.state.inputValue,
  });
};

<Form>
  <Item floatingLabel>
    <Label style={{ color: this.state.color1 }}>Email Address</Label>
    <Input />
    <Button
      onPress={() => this.navigateToCreatePasswordScreen()} // change here
      title="Navigate to Create Password"
    />
  </Item>
</Form>
```

CreatePassword.js

```
export default class CreatePasswordPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: "#A2A2A2",
    };
  }

  render() {
    // get param value
    const { inputValue } = this.props.route.params;

    return (
      <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        <Text style={styles.caption}>{inputValue}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing shows up on the createpassword page, were you able to test this? Thank you for the response!

Comment: Any other ideas? I am fairly confident my code represents yours, if you tested this I will look deeper!

Comment: That should be work, can you check `inputValue` is updating or not onChange please check first

Comment: By code is exactly how it is posted plus your edits! I updated the styles for my password page to see if maybe theres an error there? I dont think so though.